# Sql Server 2005: what data type to use to store passwords hashed by SHA-256 algorithm?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, types, passwords

In Sql Server 2005 what data type should be used to store passwords [hashed by SHA-256 algorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed(VS.71).aspx)?

The data is [hashed by the application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed(VS.71).aspx) and passed to the database

Answer (score 13):

I prefer to convert the hash-Code to an Hex-String in this case a varchar(64) will do the trick or an varchar (66) if you like a "`0x`"-prefix. In this way it is much easier to compare manually or (re)set values you have to copy/paste from other places. e.g you lost your admin-PW and want to reset it via SQL...

Answer (score 5):

varbinary(32) or binary (32).

Answer (score 4):

The "Hash" attribute of the SHA256Managed class is an array of bytes, and HashSize is 256 bits, so I believe a binary(32) would be the simplest.

You could probably also put it into a varchar field using the ToBase64Transform.  I'm not completely familiar with the Base64 Algorithm, but It seems like you would need probably need at least 43 characters to represent a 256 bit number in base 64.  IIRC Base64 uses a couple padding characters, so I'd probably put it at varchar(50) just to be safe.

Comment: I'm storing as base64 in a char(44) field. Not as wasteful as a hex-string and has the advantages Peter mentions.

Answer (score 2):

Should produce a 32-byte value (256 bits), so binary(32) ought to work.

Answer (score 1):

SHA-256 has a 256 bit output

256bits = 32 Bytes

So try varbinary(32)