# How do you store a password as a has value and then retrieve it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the code SQL:

```
create table [User] (ID int identity not null,EmailAddress varchar(50), [Password] BINARY(32),primary key (ID))
INSERT INTO [User] (EmailAddress,[Password]) values ('testuser@hotmail.co.uk',hashbytes('SHA256','test'))
```

A null value is entered into the password field.  Why is this?

I was hoping the following query would return one row, however it returns no rows:

```
SELECT * FROM [User] where password = hashbytes('sha256','test')
```

As you can probably tell I am new to hashing algorithms.

The following question states that you should store a password as a BINARY(32): [CHAR(64) or BINARY(32) To Store SHA256 Hash in SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668180/char64-or-binary32-to-store-sha256-hash-in-sql-server)

Comment: never use this, but try `hashbytes( 'SHA2_256',´test´)` you are missing numbre 2 and an undescore character in both insert and select

Comment: @Horaciux, the value is still null.

Comment: It worked for me, I posted it as an answer for you to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174415.aspx),i could see there is no Sha256 algorithm.Available ones are..

> HASHBYTES ( '', { @input | 'input' } )
>
> ::= MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512

```
select hashbytes('SHA2_256 ','test')
```

**Output:**
0x9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08

Answer (score 0):

It worked on SQL Server 2012 express

```
create table [User] (ID int identity not null,EmailAddress varchar(50), [Password] BINARY(32),primary key (ID))
INSERT INTO [User] (EmailAddress,[Password]) values ('testuser@hotmail.co.uk',hashbytes('SHA2_256','test'))

SELECT * FROM [User] where password = hashbytes('SHA2_256','test')

ID  EmailAddress    Password
1   testuser@hotmail.co.uk  0x9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm might be handled case sensitive. The case of insert and select don't match.

For finding the problem: You could select by email and print the saved password as well as the one of your 'where'-clause. So, you can see if they are actually the same.